# How to use a script to end a cron job?

Tags: bash, scripts, cron, grep

I currently have a cron job that I need to stop on shutdown.  During power off, I currently run a "shutdown" script, but I am unsure of how to take the PID number I get from `ps -ef | grep cron` and put it as the argument for `kill -9 PID`.

For the sake of clarity, I am using busybox, so functions such as pkill aren't exactly an option.

Comment: Isn't that just going to return the PID of the cron daemon anyway? How is sending it SIGKILL any different from what the shutdown command is going to do already?

Comment: The shutdown command for the script that starts the cron function is also used during update. Currently, updating hangs because it ends up just waiting for the cron process to finish up, which it never does.

Comment: @steeldriver You could use the PID for `cron` as the PPID for all processes started by `cron` and kill these. It would require an extra `grep` of course.

Comment: @Jos could you expand on that a bit? My primary issue is just the syntax for it, as I'm still learning the basics for chaining linux commands.

Comment: There are others here much better at command-line programming than me, who will happily provide a working script. (@jacobvlijm ?) First step: `ps -ef|grep cron|grep -v grep` to get the PID for `cron`. Second step: get processes whose PPID is the number obtained in the first step. Third step: kill them all.

Comment: A cron job that not terminating when complete seems like a bug. A cron job that runs too long, blocking the next job from running, also seems like a bug.

Comment: @user535733 The cron process itself is what seems to be preventing the update from running successfully.  This background process is expected to exist, and, as far as I know, this is entirely normal behaviour.

Comment: The cron daemon does not block apt  from running...nor anything else, so I wonder if your problem may be misdiagnosed, or the actual cause might be something else. Can you please edit your question to explain more information about the actual problem and show us the complete error messages?

Comment: @Jos Avoid `grep` altogether by using `pgrep` or  more suitable in this case - `pkill`

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy as I say in the OP, I am using busybox, so pkill and pgrep aren't options.

Comment: @LameOne I understand, but that wasn't comment for you. `ps|grep` is bad practice, so it has to be reminded.  Now, as for your question, why specifically kill a job during shutdown ? Is it blocking the shutdown or there's other reason ? That is, what's the actual goal ?

Answer (score 2):

Have the `cron` job record it's PID. Assuming your `cron` job is wrapped in a `bash` script, putting

```
echo "$$" >/var/run/BigJob.pid
```

at the beginning  will let you simply do

```
kill -9 `cat /var/run/BigJob.pid`
```

Comment: Or another way: `pkill -F /var/run/myProcess.pid`